# Twitter API Safe Authentication

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterizer

I'm using the C# Twitterizer in a WPF application to authenticate users to Twitter so I can publish tweets to their stream. (But that's irrelevant because the question is about the API itself).

I do not wish to create a **new** login interface, I want to use Twitter's Login page embedded in a WebBrowser control. Does Twitter **support the same authentication style** as Facebook where the user logs in to the regular FB login page and the access token is sent back in the **callback URL**? Or sending the **username and password** is the only way to get an access token (in Twitter)?!

Comment: You can, er, tone down the bolds a little ;)

Comment: Sorry about that :) it's just i think it's easier to get the idea quickly when the question's key points are highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Twitter seupports the same authentication style than Facebook called OAuth.
Facebook uses OAuth 2 and Twitter uses OAuth 1.0a

Take a look to Spring.NET Social Twitter : http://springframework.net/social-twitter/
It provides samples for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [an Oauth 1.0a class](https://cropperplugins.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Cropper.Plugins/OAuth1.0/OAuth.cs) that works with Twitter, and allows what you want.

There's also [a simple example](http://cheesoexamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/86425) that shows how to use the class.

The code looks like this:

```
OAuth.Manager oauth;
AuthSettings settings;
public void Foo()
{
    oauth = new OAuth.Manager();
    oauth["consumer_key"] = TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY;
    oauth["consumer_secret"] = TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET;

    settings = AuthSettings.ReadFromStorage();
    if (VerifyAuthentication())
    {
        Tweet("Hello, World");
    }
}

private void Tweet(string message)
{
    var url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.xml?status=" + message;
    var authzHeader = oauth.GenerateAuthzHeader(url, "POST");
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authzHeader);
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}

private bool VerifyAuthentication()
{
    if (!settings.Completed)
    {
        var dlg = new TwitterAppApprovalForm(); // your form with an embedded webbrowser
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (dlg.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            settings.access_token = dlg.AccessToken;
            settings.token_secret = dlg.TokenSecret;
            settings.Save();
        }

        if (!settings.Completed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must approve this app for use with Twitter\n" +
                            "before updating your status with it.\n\n",
                            "No Authorizaiton for TweetIt",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return false;
        }
    }

    // apply stored information into the oauth manager
    oauth["token"]           = settings.access_token;
    oauth["token_secret"]    = settings.token_secret;

    return true;
}
```

The `TwitterAppApprovalForm` is boilerplate, and is included in the example. When you have no cached access_token and token-secret, then that form pops open, hosting an embedded webbrowser that displays the Twitter authorization form.  If you have the cached data, then you don't need to display that form.